# USB bus Differential signals and Pin swapping

Tags: usb, connector, signal, differential, usb-host

[USB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB) 1.0 and 2.0 has D+ and D- two differential pins.

[image: USB Pins]

My understanding is that differential signals are symmetrical so any of the two lines carries an inverted signal of the other line.

But in the case of USB if I swap the two lines then the USB ceases to function. Is it because the USB lines are differential as well as tri-state logic also to reverse the data direction in them?

Comment: The USB receiver expects one line to be high and the other to be low, swapping them means that the signals do not come in as expected. I don't think I've seen any spec anywhere that shows USB as being "tri-state".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the receiver end, the Data- is substracted from Data+ (a difference is calculated). Then if the difference is positive, and above a threshold it is translated to a logic 1 or 0, depending on the protocol, if it is negative and below a threshold, it is translated to the opposite. By swapping the lines, you basically invert the logic levels, thus messing up the protocol.

Edit: Chris Stratton pointed out the non-differential use of the lines during speed identification. More info about this [here](https://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb2.shtml)

Comment: Yes, but there are also non-differential uses of the lines, including for initial speed identification.  One of the first things that happens with a mixup is that a high or full speed device is mis-identified as a failed low speed device, and a low speed device is mis-identified as a failed full speed device.

Comment: Information about the actual encoding can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_(Communications)

Comment: @ChrisStratton Does it means that initially the USB lines are in non-differential state and after this initial phase once the USB is ready for data communication then the lines turn into differential lines?